# Capybara visit method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I'm not sure what's going on, but I can't get simple tests to work because Capybara's visit method is not working for me. I've been trying to finish [this railscast on testing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test).

Once I get to the point where Capybara needs to visit the login page the test fails because it's only able to visit my root_url. Here's what the failure looks like. Note that it's failing because it can't even visit the login page. It's getting stuck on the homepage:

```
Running: spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--color", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "/Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@supply_side/gems/guard-rspec-0.6.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb"]...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Home | My App</title>
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="user_nav">
<li><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
      <li><a href="/login">log in</a></li>
  </ul>
<h1>Supply Side</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for My App.
</p>

<h2>Visit the <a href="/secret">Secret Page</a>.</h2>


</body>
</html>
F

Failures:

  1) PasswordResets emails user when requesting password reset
     Failure/Error: click_link "Forgot Your Password?"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no link with title, id or text 'Forgot Your Password?' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.40915 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:4 # PasswordResets emails user when requesting password reset
Done.
```

I've added the print page.html to show that it's not making it to the login page. Here's what the test looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user = Factory(:user)
    visit login_path
    print page.html
    click_link "Forgot Your Password?"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end
end
```

Here's my spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
    config.filter_run :focus => true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sorcery'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'wirble'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

My routes:

```
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :activate
    end
  end
  resources :sessions
  match "/forgot_password" => "sessions#forgot_password"
  resources :password_resets
  match "/secret" => "pages#secret"
  root :to => "pages#home"
```

And finally my config/environments/test.rb

```
 # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

I'm running Rails 3.2 on ruby 1.9.3. I'm at a loss for why this isn't working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the html that the test is printing is for my homepage, not the login page. It's failing because it can't even visit the login_path, even though login path is a valid route. This also fails: visit login_path
current_path.should == "/login"

Comment: I've also tried to see if there was a session open that was causing the test to fail, but this test shows that's not the issue: https://gist.github.com/1677202

Comment: But this test works: https://gist.github.com/1677265 So Capybara is able to use the links on the homepage to get to the login page successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test log, when the test executes visit login_path, are you initially hitting that action but then being redirected back to your homepage?

Comment: I was so early into this app that I trashed it and reinstalled everything and it's working fine. I think it was a configuration issue of some sort. Thanks for chiming in here though!

Comment: @Lee, there was a response in the google group which you posted to. You were missing the link you were testing for. As I've found in the past, always assume you've done something wrong before you've found a problem. ;-) I've come to not always trust the tests, either. Make a test pass, break it, move on.

Comment: Thanks Tass. I didn't realize someone had responded in the google group. I appreciate you taking the time to give me a heads up on a dumb question.